# Opencart 3 не работает сортировка

Tags: opencart

Не работает сортировка товаров в категории. Пробовал и вручную менять в контроллере и в адресной строке get параметры прописывал по типу &sort=p.price&order=ASC , и в самом контролере прописывал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл сказать , версия Opencart 3.0.2.0

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/868626/edit), расположенную под вопросом. Код кстати лучше вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.